# Multiple Clipboard Project From Automatetheboringstuff not working

Tags: python

I'm going through the automatetheboringstuff website for learning Python.  I completed the Chapter 8 project for a multiple clipboard script but it isn't working.  It should save whatever is on my clipboard to a shelf file with a keyword if I pass the 'save' argument, it should copy whatever matches a keyword when I pass that keyword, and if I pass 'list' it should copy all the keywords to the clipboard.  When I try to run the script using any of the keywords, nothing really happens.  Whatever I have on the clipboard doesn't change.

I'm not seeing what I did wrong with my code, any ideas?

```
#! python 3
# mcb.pyw - Saves and loads pieces of text to the clipboard.
# Usage: py.exe mcb.pyw save <keyword> - Saves clipboard to keyword.
#       py.exe mcb.pyw <keyword> - Loads keyword to clipboard.
#       py.exe mcb.pyw list - Loads all keywords to clipboard.


import shelve, pyperclip, sys

mcbShelf = shelve.open('mcb')


# Save clipboard content.

if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'save':
    mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste()

elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
    # List keywords and load content.

    if sys.argv[1].lower() == 'list':
        pyperclip.copy(str(list(mcbShelf.keys())))

    elif sys.argv[1] in mcbShelf:
        pyperclip.copy(mcbShelf[sys.argv[1]])


mcbShelf.close()
```

EDIT:  I have another script that uses pyperclip and the batch file and script are stored in the exact same locations and the other script works while this one does not change anything on the clipboard.  Could this mean something is going wrong with the shelve module?

Comment: As a first debugging step, add some print messages to the `if` and `else` clauses so you know what code is being executed.

Comment: code works for me on Linux Mint, Python 3. It changes text in clipboard - I can use Ctrl+V to take new text from clipboard.

Comment: When I try to run it from the Run Box I get the prompt  'Press any key to continue.' but it doesn't change anything on the clipboard.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My OS - Ubuntu, Python  3.

I installed modulles, as it is pointed in - https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#not-implemented-error.
Then it was worked. And instead of pyw extension used py.

Run code (in terminal Ubuntu):
*python3 mcb.py*

Save any datа from bufer to file:
*python3 mcb.py save anydata*

Read any data from file to bufer:
*python3 mcb.py anydata*